# Как в blade в одну таблицу вывести 3 массива?

Tags: php, laravel, blade

```
@for($i = 1; $i < count($time)+1; $i++)
        @foreach($time as $tm)
            @foreach($title as $tt)
                @foreach($subtitle as $st)
    <tr>
        <td class="round-top">{{$i}}</td>
        <td>{{$today}}</td>
        <td>{{$tm}}</td>
        <td>{{$tt}}</td>
        <td>{{$st}}</td>
    </tr>
        @endforeach
            @endforeach
            @endforeach
    @endfor
```

Но если выводить так записи в таблице дублируются, как этого избежать?

```
$time, $title, $subtitle = массивы со строками
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@for($i = 0; $i < count($time); $i++)
    <tr>
        <td class="round-top">{{ $i + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $today }}</td>
        <td>{{ $time[$i] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $title[$i] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $subtitle[$i] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endfor
```